# Check if Datatable contains content of second Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to compare two datatable and simply check if Datatable(A) contains rows which are in Datatable(B).

Then rows from (B) which will not be in (A) will be inserted into (A). So basically target is to insert rows from (B) into (A) but only those rows which are not already presented.

Both Datables have same structure, same columns and datatypes.

I don´t want to do it with foreach loop for every Datarow(B) and compare with every Datarow in (A) it will be very slow solutions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please add some of your code, what you want to accomplish, what you've tried?

Comment: You probably want to use the Linq `Except` extension method, but don't think that it doesn't do any looping in its internal implementation.

Comment: I don´t have code. Simply what I want to accomplish is to transfer content ob (B) into (A) but only those rows which are not present already in (A)

Comment: If you don't have any code then it's premature to post here.  Do the appropriate research, write the code you think is required and then, if it doesn't work, you can post here and show us what you've done.

Comment: Please [research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) your question. If you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Use a join :             var results = from rowa in dta.AsEnumerable()
                          join rowb in dtb.AsEnumerable() on rowa.ItemArray equals rowb.ItemArray
                          select rowa;